# How to calculate summation

Tags: summation, poisson-distribution

$P(q|N)=\frac{e^{-\eta N}\cdot (\eta N)^q}{q!}$ complies with conditional Poisson distribution where $\eta$ is constant parameter and $P(N)\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$. I'm trying to prove $P(q)=\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}P(q|N)P(N)\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\eta \lambda)$.

After simple calculation this problem reduces to the proof of equation $\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\eta N}\cdot (\eta N)^q \lambda^N}{N!}=e^{-\eta \lambda}\cdot (\eta \lambda)^q\cdot e^\lambda$.

Can anyone help me to prove or disprove it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: My gut feeling says that the equality is not true. One way to prove this could be to identify (up to constant factors) the sum as the $q$-th moment of a Poisson distribution.

Comment: Indeed the right hand side grows like $O(\lambda^q)$ while the left hand side is $O(1)$ (for $\lambda\to 0$)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Actually it's my fault not to specify the parameters range. I extracted this proposition from a realistic physical problem where $\lambda$ is a large number and $\eta$ is close to $0^{+}$. Further derivation based on the answer given by Jacob proves the equality approximately holds for my case.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{N = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( e^{-\eta} \lambda \right)^{N}}{N!}
= \exp\!\left( \exp\!\left( -\eta\right) \lambda \right) 
\end{align*}
which we can differentiate $q$ times with respect to $\eta$ since it's a power series (uniform convergence)
to obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{N = 0}^{\infty } 
\frac{1}{N!}{\frac{\partial^{q} }{\partial \eta^{q}} \left( e^{-\eta N}\right)\lambda ^{N}}
= \sum_{N = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{N!} {e^{-\eta N}N^{q}( -\eta)^{q}\lambda ^{N}}
= \frac{\partial ^{q}}{\partial \eta^{q}} \exp\!\left( \exp\!\left( -\eta\right) \lambda \right) 
.\end{align*}
Does this help answering your question?

Comment: Thank you very very much!! Your answer is exactly what I'm looking for! Even though the equation I want to prove doesn't strictly holds, when $\eta$ is sufficiently close to $0^{+}$ the equation holds, which is the case in my problem.